# Jquery ajax POST request to Rails (xml) action

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

Hi we are trying to post data using xml to another rails app.

On the destination app I have this code

```
class DaemonsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token 
respond_to :xml, :html


def new
 respond_with(@daemon = Daemon.new)
end

def create
 @daemon = Daemon.new(params[:daemon])
 if @daemon.save
   #redirect_to @daemon, :notice => "Successfully created daemon."
   respond_with(@daemon, :location => daemons_url)
 else
   render :action => 'new'
 end
end
end
```

So XML is allowed for posting data.
In my other app I'm using jquery for the data posting

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:3000/daemons.xml",
  data: "<daemon><mac>abc</mac><status>1</status></daemon>",

  contentType: 'application/xml; charset=utf-8', // format of request payload
  dataType: 'html', // format of the response
  success: function(msg) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  }
  });
```

But this returns an error :

```
Started OPTIONS "/daemons.xml" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-30 12:04:05 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/daemons.xml"):
```

When I post the same data using a curl command, everything is working fine

```
curl -i -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' http://localhost:3000/daemons -d '<daemon><mac>ABC</mac><status>1</status></daemon>'
HTTP/1.1 201 Created 
Location: http://localhost:3000/daemons
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge
X-Runtime: 0.195632
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-02-18)
Date: Mon, 30 May 2011 10:02:40 GMT
Content-Length: 291
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<daemon>
<created-at type="datetime">2011-05-30T10:02:39Z</created-at>
<id type="integer">2</id>
<mac-address nil="true"></mac-address>
<status type="integer">1</status>
<updated-at type="datetime">2011-05-30T10:02:39Z</updated-at>
```

This commes up in the webbrick logs

```
Started POST "/daemons" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-30 12:02:39 +0200
Processing by DaemonsController#create as 
Parameters: {"daemon"=>{"mac"=>"ABC", "status"=>"1"}}
AREL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "daemons" ("mac", "status", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (ABC, 1, '2011-05-30 10:02:39.920672', '2011-05-30 10:02:39.920672')
```

Does someone know what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

cURL command is using http://localhost:3000/daemons, while your jQuery is using http://localhost:3000/daemons.xml?

Comment: Hi Jack,
I tried the both, they both work with curl.
Only with javascript they don't.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with jquery 1.4.x and an older version of rails.js when making a cross site ajax request.  I upgraded to jquery 1.6 and the newest rails.js and that seemed to fix it.  FWIW, this had to do with setting the CSRF token in the ajax request header.  Disabling CSRF protection on the calling side would work as well.